# Chapter style minimal design

Tags: titlesec

I am approaching LaTex to write my thesis and I have some problems on Chapter style format. I started to read some articles online and the manual of titlesec package, but they are to difficult for me that I am at the beginning of LaTex.
I would have a simple style like the picture below.
The section can be displayed as standard.
Is there anyone that can help me?

Thanks and sorry for the low level question!

[image: Chapter style needed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will set the chapter number at the very top of the page (save for a few points).

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\sffamily\bfseries\filright}
  {\hrule height 0pt \huge\thechapter\hrule}
  {-\baselineskip}
  {\Huge\strut}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}
  {-\topskip}
  {2\normalbaselineskip}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

The first picture shows the result, the second picture is the same with the `showframe` package active.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am swinging the bat of a large and unneeded(*) package / style here: use `memoir`.

The point is, memoir has *many* different chapter styles built-in.

[image: demo2 style]
[image: chappel style]
[image: bianchi style]

The usage is simple:

> To use the chapterstyle `fred` just issue the command 
>   `\chapterstyle{fred}`

If you want more stock styles, http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles/ has them.

You can start with a particular style and then further mod it, too.

---

(*): For the sake of this question `memoir` is indeed too much. There was also an option to use those styles separately from memoir, in fact. But for the sake of writing a large document (i.e., a thesis) I highly recommend something more advanced and stable. That is, `memoir`. Many people also use `KOMA script`, `classicthesis` is done specially for the goal of thesis writing, but I have never used it myself. I tried `tufte-latex` and it was not very comfortable for writing a large document. I mean that it required a bit more fiddling with layout than I was comfortable with *before* obtaining a passable version and further tweaking it into oblivion. (And also my adviser did not like it, which was an even more important factor.)

To put it short, typical tasks like "squeeze two figures side by side, while still looking good" or "how to put an epigraph at chapter start" or "put a yet another line on this page, pretty-pretty please!" work easier at least in `memoir`, people with knowledge on other classes might comment on them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with `titlesec` and a standard class:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\sffamily\bfseries\filright}{\huge\thechapter\vspace{-1.5ex}\newline\mbox{}\titlerule [1pt]}{1.5ex}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-32pt}{48pt}%

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{Chapter title}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]